# build and run tensorflow lite demo with gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

so recently according to this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15633#issuecomment-377652630) tensorflow lite now supports
the mobilenet_ssd for object detection. Which is great..
I managed to build and run the demo with bazel but originaly I wanted to do that with Android Studio. Unfortunately I couldn't do it.

Here is the error that I'm getting :

```
Error:Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

Reading through the comments it seems I'm not the only one confused about this. Is there a solution for this ? or there is no gradle support at the moment for this particular update ?

Any information that could clarify this problem is much appreciated since I'm still new to the AI world.

Answer (score 2):

Here are instructions for building and running the following (22 Aug 2018) TensorFlow Lite Android examples in both Bazel (Method 1) and Gradle (Method 2);

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android (classification/detection/etc)
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo (classification)

---

## How to get the TensorFlow Lite Android examples to run [tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android];

(e.g. object detection/ssd models; detect.tflite[/mobilenet_ssd.tflite]/coco_labels_list.txt)

Instructions based on; https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193

### Method 1 (Bazel)

- `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`
- OPTIONAL: `git checkout master` / `938a3b77797164db736a1006a7656326240baa59`

  - [these instructions are based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/938a3b77797164db736a1006a7656326240baa59 ]
- `gedit WORKSPACE`, and add references to android_sdk_repository and android_ndk_repository;

  ```
  android_sdk_repository(
      name = "androidsdk",
      api_level = 28,
      build_tools_version = "28.0.1",
      # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
      path = "/[INSERTCORRECTPATHHERE]/android-sdk-linux",
  )
  android_ndk_repository(
     name="androidndk",
     path="/[INSERTCORRECTPATHHERE]/android-ndk-r14b",
     api_level=28)
  ```
- [This prevents the following error:

  ```
  ERROR: /.../tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD:620:1: no such package '@androidndk//': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal:cpu_check'
  ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android:tflite_demo' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
  FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (60 packages loaded)]
  ```
- [Note android-ndk-r14b is required for Bazel according to https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193 ]
- `bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm --cxxopt='--std=c++11' //tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android:tflite_demo`
- `adb install bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android/tflite_demo.apk`
- Run example app (tflDetect) on Android phone (search - tflDetect)
- [give permissions to app when requested]

### Method 2 (Gradle)

- `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`
- OPTIONAL: `git checkout master` / `938a3b77797164db736a1006a7656326240baa59`

  - [these instructions are based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/938a3b77797164db736a1006a7656326240baa59 ]
- OPTIONAL: extract tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android folder from tensorflow
- Open the tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android directory in Android Studio project.
- [Install all the Gradle extensions it requests.]
- modify app/build.gradle;

  - remove (comment out) this; `jackOptions { enabled true }`
  - change `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'` to `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.10.0'` [latest working revision] (or `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'`
- [This prevents the following error:

  ```
  08-22 05:03:19.470 24480-24480/org.tensorflow.lite.demo W/System.err: TensorFlowLite: failed to load native library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__android_log_vprint" referenced by "/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.demo-2/lib/arm/libtensorflowlite_jni.so"...
  08-22 02:48:55.728 29643-29643/org.tensorflow.lite.demo E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper]
  ```
- Gradle Sync
- Build
- Run
- [give permissions to app when requested]
- Run example app (tflDetect) on Android phone (search - tflDetect)

Note if an error is thrown upon run, e.g.;

```
    Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573))
    Error while Installing APKs
    ...
    Installation failed with message Invalid File: /.../app/build/intermediates/split-apk/debug/slices/slice_5.apk.
    It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
    WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
    Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Then try one of the following;

- Restart the phone, and re-run the application
- Build - Rebuild project, and re-run the application

[EDIT: 
To get optional object tracking to work, `libtensorflow_demo.so` is required to be installed;

- Assume the TensorFlow Lite Android examples with Gradle (Method 2) instructions above have already been completed
- Execute the TensorFlow Lite Android examples with Bazel (Method 1) instructions above - this will install a working version of the Android examples with `libtensorflow_demo.so`
- `libtensorflow_demo.so` now needs to be extracted from the installed apk on the Android device
- Open Android studio - View - Tool Windows - Device File Explorer
- Ensure Android device is selected
- `/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.demo/lib/arm` - Right click `libtensorflow_demo.so` - Save as - save to temporary folder on hard drive
- create folder `tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/jniLibs`
- create 4 subfolders (`jniLibs/arm64-v8a`, `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a`, `jniLibs/x86`, `jniLibs/x86_64`)
- place `libtensorflow_demo.so` in all subfolders
- Open `tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/android` in Android Studio
- Build again using Gradle
- Run ]

---

## How to get the TensorFlow Lite Java Demo to run [tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo]

(e.g. classification models; mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite/labels_mobilenet_quant_v1_224.txt)

Instructions based on; https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_android

### Method 1 (Bazel)

See https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_android / https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/README.md (not tested)

### Method 2 (Gradle)

- `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`
- OPTIONAL: `git checkout master` / `938a3b77797164db736a1006a7656326240baa59`

  - [these instructions are based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/938a3b77797164db736a1006a7656326240baa59 ]
- OPTIONAL: extract tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo folder from tensorflow
- Open the tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo directory in Android Studio project.
- [Install all the Gradle extensions it requests.]
- edit app - build.gradle;

  - change `androidTestCompile('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'` to `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'`
  - change `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'` to `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.10.0'` [latest working revision] (or `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'`
- [This prevents the following error:

  ```
  08-22 05:03:19.470 24480-24480/org.tensorflow.lite.demo W/System.err: TensorFlowLite: failed to load native library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__android_log_vprint" referenced by "/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.demo-2/lib/arm/libtensorflowlite_jni.so"...
  08-22 02:48:55.728 29643-29643/org.tensorflow.lite.demo E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper]
  ```
- [When requested select; 'add Maven repository and sync project']
- Gradle Sync
- Build
- Run
- [Run demo app (tflitecamerademo) on Android phone (search - tflitecamerademo)]
- [give permissions to app when requested]